# How to create a nested array of JSON objects using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

Desired output:

```
{"MainKey": 
   [{"key01":"value01","key02":"value02"},
    {"key11":"value11","key22":"value02"}
   ]
}
```

The code I tried:

```
data = {}
data2=[{}]

data2[0]['key01'] = 'value01'
data2[0]['key02']=  'value02'

data2[1]['key11'] = 'value11'  #index out of bounds error
data2[1]['key12']=  'value12'

data['MainKey']=data2

import json 
with open('try.json", 'w') as outfile:
 json.dump(data,outfile)
```

But this gives index out of bounds error for the second set of values in data2. How do i solve this?

Comment: You are getting the error because you only have one dict in `data2` try: `data2=[{}, {}]`

Comment: @Rakesh How would i make an array with n number of such items though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to create the number of dict using `range`.

**Ex:**

```
data = {}

data2 = [{} for i in range(2)]

data2[0]['key01'] = 'value01'
data2[0]['key02']=  'value02'

data2[1]['key11'] = 'value11'
data2[1]['key12']=  'value12'

data['MainKey']=data2
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'MainKey': [{'key01': 'value01', 'key02': 'value02'}, {'key12': 'value12', 'key11': 'value11'}]}
```

Comment: Please accept ans if it solved your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

data2 is a list with only one item, so its index cannot be greater than 0.

```
>>> data2=[{}]
>>> data2[0]['key01'] = 'value01'
>>> data2[0]['key02'] = 'value02'
>>> data2
```

[{'key01': 'value01', 'key02': 'value02'}]

Comment: I figured, but how do i solve this and make an array with n number of {} items in data2?

Comment: `data2 = [{} for i in range(n)]`